# Unable to click the radio buttons other than the checked one in JSP

Tags: jsp, servlets, for-loop, radio-button

This is my jsp page

```
    <%!
    // Table row colors
    static final String[] COLORS = { "#E0E0E0", "#F0F0F0" };

    // Array of tab codes, labels and JSP names
    static final String[][] TABS = {
                                    {"HD", "Headers", "ShowRequestHeaders.jsp"} ,
                                    {"PM", "Parameters", "ShowParameters.jsp"},
                                    {"SR", "ServletRequest Methods", "ShowServletRequestMethodValues.jsp"},
                                    {"HR", "HttpServletRequest Methods", "ShowHttpServletRequestMethodValues.jsp"} 
    };


%>
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Show Request</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Show Request</h2>
    <form >
        <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                    <%
                        String which = request.getParameter("which");
                        if (which == null)
                            which = TABS[0][0]; //HD
                        String jspToRun = null;
                        for (int i = 0; i < TABS.length; i++) {

                            String tabCode = TABS[i][0];
                            String tabLabel = TABS[i][1];
                            String tabJSP = TABS[i][2];
                            String CHECKED = "";
                            if (which.equals(tabCode)) {

                                CHECKED = "CHECKED";
                                jspToRun = tabJSP;
                            }
                    %> <input name="which" type="RADIO" value= "<%=tabCode%>"
                                                                <%=CHECKED%> onClick="this.form.submit()"
                                                                 >
                                                                <%=tabLabel%>

                    <%
                        }
                    %>
                    <p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">

                <!-- Page showing details of the request -->
                <jsp:include page="<%= jspToRun %>" flush="true"></jsp:include>
```

Different jsp's are included depending on the radio button clicked. When i tried to check a radio button other than the checked one, there is no change. Kindly help me out.

Comment: Are you sure your page is submitting? I copied and pasted your code (closing the HTML tags) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the below JSP file worked fine for me. When I click a radio button the form is submitted and the corresponding JSP file is included when the page is refreshed.

Note that I have called the **main** JSP file `index.jsp` and included the other JSP files in the same directory.

```
<%!// Table row colors
static final String[] COLORS = { "#E0E0E0", "#F0F0F0" };

// Array of tab codes, labels and JSP names
static final String[][] TABS = {
        { "HD", "Headers", "ShowRequestHeaders.jsp" },
        { "PM", "Parameters", "ShowParameters.jsp" },
        { "SR", "ServletRequest Methods",
                "ShowServletRequestMethodValues.jsp" },
        { "HR", "HttpServletRequest Methods",
                "ShowHttpServletRequestMethodValues.jsp" } };%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Show Request</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Show Request</h2>
<form>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                <%
                    String which = request.getParameter("which");
                    if (which == null)
                        which = TABS[0][0]; //HD
                    String jspToRun = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < TABS.length; i++) {

                        String tabCode = TABS[i][0];
                        String tabLabel = TABS[i][1];
                        String tabJSP = TABS[i][2];
                        String CHECKED = "";
                        if (which.equals(tabCode)) {

                            CHECKED = "CHECKED";
                            jspToRun = tabJSP;
                        }
                %> <input name="which" type="RADIO" value="<%=tabCode%>"
                <%=CHECKED%> onClick="this.form.submit()"> <%=tabLabel%>     <%
}
 %>
                <p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
                <!-- Page showing details of the request --> <jsp:include
                    page="<%=jspToRun%>" flush="true"></jsp:include>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Generated HTML.  Note that I just used the file name as the contents for the include JSP files:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Show Request</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Show Request</h2>
<form>
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
        <tr>
            <td align="left">
                 <input name="which" type="RADIO" value="HD"
                CHECKED onClick="this.form.submit()"> Headers  <input name="which" type="RADIO" value="PM"
                 onClick="this.form.submit()"> Parameters  <input name="which" type="RADIO" value="SR"
                 onClick="this.form.submit()"> ServletRequest Methods  <input name="which" type="RADIO" value="HR"
                 onClick="this.form.submit()"> HttpServletRequest Methods 
                <p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td align="center" valign="top">
                <!-- Page showing details of the request --> ShowRequestHeaders.jsp

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens when you clicked the radio button other than the checked one. Let say there are 3 radio buttons, 3 jsp files excluding index.jsp. Do you see different content below the radio buttons in index.jsp when you navigate from one radio button to other.

Comment: Yes, I see the other content when I select the non-default radio button.  I'll update my answer to show the generated HTML.